# SQL automatic query analysis for involved tables/columns

Tags: sql, code-analysis

Let‘s say we have got a large number of SQL queries which take a long time to run. Now, we would like to make some changes to the database and re-execute the queries. We could rerun everything, but I would prefer a solution where only those queries are executed which are affected by the changes.
Do you know of any method to obtain the relevant tables/columns for each query? A simple example would be:

(let's consider this table: TABLE1 with columns: A;B;C)

```
SELECT C FROM TABLE1 WHERE B>10;
```

I would like to know that TABLE1.B is participating in this query.

Edit: the database is HSQLDB and is used from Java via JDBC.

Comment: you don't have much choice.  you either parse the sql with some external parser, or you run it and let the databse parse it for you and maybe save off some metadata bout each SQL statement

Comment: @Randy using the metadata sounds interesting, but as far as I know, I can only get the returned column names (and not the ones from the where statement).

Comment: check the results of the EXPLAIN PLAN or execution plan on your system.. that should be parse-able.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any workbenck to execute your sql queries ? In Mysql workbench you have query optimizer option under which you can check which query has excuter and what actions has performed with the query result in a tree block diagram which certainly helps you here and you can also parse your query and check your resuls in query optimizer :) Hope it helps to you.